# Changing Border of WPF Tab Control Dynamically

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate, wpf-style

I'm using my own control template for the TabControl and TabItem in the application resource of my project.

In the template, the selected TabItem is colored depending on a property 'SelectedBrush' which returns a Brush. I would also like the Border of the Tab Control (`boTabControl`, the border around the content presenter) to do be the same color as the selected TabItem.

Is this a code thing, or can it be done in the application resource?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,3,0,0" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Border x:Name="boTabControl" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1,3,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SelectedBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="0"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="boTabControl" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding SelectedBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="boTabControl" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="Panel" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0,0,-3,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="10,30,0,0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ContentSource="Header" Margin="10"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedBrush As Brush
    Get
        If Me.tcMain.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            Return Brushes.Aquamarine
            Exit Property
        End If
        Dim myTabItem As TabItem = Me.tcMain.SelectedItem
        Dim myBrush As Brush = Brushes.Blue
        Select Case myTabItem.Name
            Case Me.tiSale.Name
                myBrush = Brushes.Green
            Case Me.tiReturn.Name
                myBrush = Brushes.Red
            Case Me.tiStock.Name
                myBrush = Brushes.Black
            Case Me.tiAdmin.Name
                myBrush = Brushes.Purple
        End Select

        Return myBrush
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: more details about "function 'SelectedBrush'"? also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232502/template-binding-with-attached-properties) shows a nice approach to parametrize templates

Comment: I've added the SelectedBrush function at the bottom of the code. This code sits in the Form that hosts the Tab Control

Comment: NB: SelectedBrush is actually a property not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an approach with an attached property SelectedBrush of type `Brush`

add Attached class to project (and make build):

```
public class Attached
{
    public static DependencyProperty SelectedBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Attached));

    public static Brush GetSelectedBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush) obj.GetValue(SelectedBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedBrushProperty, value);
    }
}
```

then assign colors to each TabItem:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="tiSale" local:Attached.SelectedBrush="Green" Header="123"/>
    <TabItem Name="tiReturn" local:Attached.SelectedBrush="Red" Header="abc"/>
    <TabItem Name="tiStock" local:Attached.SelectedBrush="Black" Header="XYZ"/>
</TabControl>
```

change TabControl template to use `Attached.SelectedBrush`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,3,0,0" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Border x:Name="boTabControl" Grid.Row="1" 
                            BorderThickness="1,3,0,0" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.(local:Attached.SelectedBrush), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            CornerRadius="0" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="0"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

to use the same brush for TabItem, change Background setter like this:

```
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" 
        Value="{Binding (local:Attached.SelectedBrush), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

`SelectedBrush` property from code behind is not used here

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'll check it out later. One question in the meantime...will this deal with making the various tab items gray when they are not selected?

Comment: @RhydianCoombs, it will with minor modification (see edit). didn't notice SelectedBrush was used in TabItem template because that part of code was hidden by long horizontal scroll

Comment: Thanks so much for the info you provided. It was a great and have got it all working.

Rhyd.

Comment: Apologies. Not posted much on this site. Should be accepted now